# What is the best web viewable format to save a TIF with a 1 bit depth?

Tags: c#, .net, image, tiff

I want to convert `TIF` to an image type that is viewable in a web page.

The `TIFs` are black and white so `JPG` does not work well at all and ends up even larger after conversion.

Here are some tests I have performed using C# and `Image.Save` to do the conversion:

Orignal `TIF` is 7KB (bit depth: 1).

Converted to:

- JPG: 101KB (bit depth: 24)
- BMP: 256KB (bit depth: 1)
- GIF: 17KB (bit depth: 8)
- PNG: 11KB (bit depth: 1)

I then converted a multipage `TIF` which has 3 pages.  Original size was 134KB (bit depth: 1).

Converted 3 images totals:

- JPG: 1324KB (bit depth: 24)
- BMP: 768KB (bit depth: 1)
- GIF: 221KB (bit depth: 8)
- PNG: 155KB (bit depth: 1)

I am starting with a multipage `TIF` and I need to convert to be viewable in a browser.  It looks like `PNG` would be the best format to use based on my basic tests I have outlined above.  Are there other image formats that I should be using / considering?

Are the any other options I am missing to get the file size down?

**EDIT:** I haved added more information regarding the bit depth of each format.  The `BMP` and `PNG` maintain the same bit depth as the `TIF`.  Is there a way to reduce the `GIF` or `JPG` bit depth to hopefully reduce the size significantly?

Comment: Is it truly black and white, or is it grayscale?

Comment: Good question.  I 'think' it is black and white.  Every black pixel looks to be the same shade of black ;)  I don't know much about the tif format.  Will look into this more when I have access to some examples and post.

Comment: I have added the various bit depth for the tiff and my resulting images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PNG is certainly your best choice here.

The reason your PNG ends up larger than the original TIF might be that the runtime doesn't do all the compression it possibly could. If you really need to compress every last little byte out of the PNG file, I would suggest using a tool like [AdvancePNG](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/comp-readme.html) or [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) in order to compress the PNGs after you write them out. The author of OptiPNG has written a good article with links to a [few other PNG optimizers](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html).

Comment: TIFF has superior compression for 1-bit images. For all other kinds, it loses to PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Use PNG, it supports 1-bit color mode and works even in IE4 (if you don't need partial transparency). Do your customers use IE3?

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I might have shied away from PNG, but now it just works. and there are plenty of hack scripts to get it to work with IE 5 and 6 so you can be safe for most users. If you really need compatibility offer both GIF & PNG.

Comment: This question is not about alpha transparency. Also, PNG supports a /sbin/fsck-load of modes, not just RGBA.

Comment: Just why in the world would anyone need a GIF? If you're talking about alpha transparency, isn't it better to provide just two PNG files? Your site won't even load in IE3 anyway.

Comment: There's more to PNG & GIF then transparency guys. They are the best algorithms for encoding 1-bit black & white images as well.

Comment: You'll notice that their file sizes are smaller than BMP & JPG. PNG is the number 1 choice, and if legacy compatibility is 100% required then GIF is the natural alternative.